# F#: how to have the variables defined above a XUnit test function actually initialized when running the test?

Tags: f#, initialization, xunit

Following up another question: [F#: Why those two collections are not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56484369/f-why-those-two-collections-are-not-equal) the example below shows that when running `Open an account...` test `id` and `contact` are not initialized.

If there were functions returning the same values and called in the test body it would work though.

I am wondering why this is case, and if there is anything I can do to have those variables properly initialized when the test is running.

```ml
let id = Guid.Empty
let contact = {
    Name = {
        FirstName = "Marcel"
        MiddleInitial = None
        LastName = "Patulacci"
    }
    DateOfBith = new DateTime(1850, 12, 25)
    Address = {
        Address1 = "41 av 8 Mai 1945"
        Address2 = None
        City = "Sarcelles"
        State = None
        Zip = "95200"
    }
    PhoneNumber = {
        DialOutCode = 33
        LocalNumber = "766030703"
    }
    Email = "marcel.patulacci@outlook.com"
}

[<Fact>]
let ``Open an account...``() =
    let event = Event.AccountOpened({
        AccountId = id
        Contact = contact
    })

    let a = [event]
    let b = seq { yield event }

    Assert.Equal(a, b)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is down to how F# modules are implemented in .NET IL. Modules are compiled into static classes, and module-defined values are initialized in the class's static constructor. But because of the way XUnit loads tests, the static constructor is not run.

A possible way to circumvent this is to use a class instead of a module, as XUnit does run *instance* constructors. `let` functions in a class are compiled to private methods, so the tests are recognized by XUnit without having to switch to `member` syntax.

```
type MyTests() =

    let id = Guid.Empty
    let contact = // ...

    [<Fact>]
    let ``Open an account...``() =
        // ...
```

Comment: I knew there was something "fishy", that's smart! 
Thanks a million!

Comment: another way out is to actually not use XUnit but rather NUnit (https://github.com/nunit/nunit-fsharp-samples). 
This is out of the scope of my question (XUnit) but might worth being check out.