# XUnit/FsUnit framework throwing "Object reference not set to an instance of an objct"

Tags: f#, xunit, fsunit

I have written this simple test case for my code

```ml
module CustomerTests
open Xunit
open FsUnit
open MyProject.Customer
open MyProject.Customer.Domain
    
module ``When upgrading customer`` = 
  let customerVIP = {Id = 1; IsVip = true; Credit = 0.0M}
  let customerSTD = {Id = 2; IsVip = false; Credit = 100.0M}
  [<Fact>]
  let ``should give VIP customer more credit`` () =
    let expected = {customerVIP with Credit = customerVIP.Credit + 100.0M }
    let actual = upgradeCustomer customerVIP
    actual |> should equal expected
```

Very surprisingly this code fails with error

```
[xUnit.net 00:00:00.64] CustomerTests+When upgrading customer.should give VIP cstomer more credit [FAIL]
  Failed CustomerTests+When upgrading customer.should give VIP cstomer more credit [3 ms]
  Error Message:
  System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Stack Trace:
    at CustomerTests.When upgrading customer.should give VIP cstomer more credit() in /Users/user/code/fsharp/CustomerProject/CustomerTests.fs:line 12
```

But line 12 is just a record being created so its not possible for that line to throw an Object reference not set to an instance of object. This is totally puzzling me.

In the `dotnet fsi` repl I can execute all my method and there is no object reference problem in my function which are being called from my tests here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56486569/344223) explains, XUnit loads the test in a way that skips initialization of those values. One easy fix is to use a class instead of a module:

```ml
type ``When upgrading customer``() =

    let customerVIP = {Id = 1; isVip = true; Credit = 0.0M}
    let customerSTD = {Id = 2; isVip = false; Credit = 100.0M}

    [<Fact>]
    let ``should give VIP cstomer more credit`` () =
        let expected = {customerVIP with Credit = customerVIP.Credit + 100.0M }
        let actual = upgradeCustomer customerVIP
        actual |> should equal expected
```

That way, initialization of those values happens as it should.

Comment: yes this works. but also gives a warning `warning FS0988: Main module of program is empty: nothing will happen when it is run` any idea how to write test without the warning?

Comment: I think that happens because you've defined your project as a Console Application (.exe), rather than a Class Library (.dll). You can change the project type by removing this line from the .fsproj file: `<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>`

Comment: That does not work. (sorry I am a newbie) if I remove that line and run `dotnet test` I get error `Testhost process for source(s) '/Users/abhisheksrivastava/code/fsharp/CustomerProject/bin/Debug/net6.0/CustomerProject.dll' exited with error: Error:
  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (CustomerProject.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'FSharp.Core', version: '6.0.6'
    path: 'lib/netstandard2.1/FSharp.Core.dll'
. Please check the diagnostic logs for more information.
Test Run Aborted.`

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure why that would happen. Try switching the project back to a console app again, and just add this line at the bottom of your test file: `module Program = [<EntryPoint>] let main args = 0`. The warning message is just telling you that your executable doesn't have an entry point, so we can easily make one that does nothing.